# Marshal::copy with CvMat

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cli

I need to send an image into a byte array using c++/cli. The image is initially in Iplimage format.

```
    int img_sz1 = img1->width * img1->height * img1->nChannels;
    array <Byte>^ hh1 = gcnew array<Byte> (img_sz1);
    Marshal::Copy( (IntPtr)img->imageData, hh1, 0, img_sz1 );
```

and it was working fine.

I added the encoding step to send it as jpeg

```
    CvMat* buf1 = cvEncodeImage(".jpeg", img1, jpeg_params);
    img_sz1=buf1->width*buf1->height 
    Marshal::Copy( (IntPtr)buf1, hh1, 0, img_sz1 );
```

and now it compiles fine but gives me the error at the marshal:copy line

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in   
 mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: In the latter case, are you also resizing `hh1` to match `buf1->width*buf1->height` rather than `img1->width * img1->height * img1->nChannels`? Or, alternatively, is `buf1->width*buf1->height` erroneously not taking into account `nChannels`?

Comment: There is no nchannels parameter in the encoded buffer. Probably because all the channels are encoded now into one jpeg stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return of `cvEncodeImage` is a single-row matrix, containing the encoded image data. What you're copying now is the struct itself, e.g., the width field, the height field, etc. I believe you need to copy from `buf1->data` instead.

Comment: I tried buf1->data.ptr and it compiled. I still need to test if I'm getting the correct image.